# Surface charge density of uniformly Polarised Sphere

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics

In an introduction to electromagnetism we learnt that the bound surface charge density can be found by taking the scalar product of the Polarisation vector $\vec P$ and the vector normal to the surface $\vec n$: \begin{equation}
\sigma_b =\vec P\cdot \vec n
\end{equation}

My problem with this is that if, for example, we have a uniformly polarised sphere, the direction of the normal vector is not constant.  Can this formula still be used?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is precisely the point. The surface charge is not uniform - it is zero at the equator, where it changes sign, and maximal at the poles - and this spatial variation is directly captured by the changes in the inner product between the polarization vector (which is constant) and the changing direction of the surface's normal vector.

Comment: OK. So can this formula be used, for instance, to find the electric field inside the sphere ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. You should find that the surface charge produces a uniform electric field inside, and a pure dipole field outside.